# Parsing with Queue by Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Have a big json source, but with pagination.So I chunked it on 400jobs with 100 elements of items per page. Everything is ok, but it takes so long time for processing all jobs.
Did someone have same issue before,maybe different way? Think about RabbitMQ and etc but maybe other way?

Comment: More queue workers will permit you to go through the queued jobs faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Supervisor, try to increase value of `numprocs` in `laravel-worker.conf`.